# d3.max return wrong date

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js, max

I have a kind a weird problem. I'm loading data for a overview page. I need to show max date, so users know which time period they're dealing with. Now, I know which date this should be (today or yesterdays date, this is updated once a night) but I would like to do a max function anyway, in case something goes wrong during the update.

The problem I'm having is that both d3.max and a custom max-date function returns the wrong date. One month in the future, so today should show 7/9 2015 but instead it displays 7/10 2015. When I filter the data on 7/10 i get an empty array. In fiddle this works alright so there is something fishy going on. I do run an d3.tsv(tsv is right, even if the extension says .csv the file is in fact tab-separated), might be something there that's causing trouble? Any ideas where i might go wrong? The parsefunction alone returns the right results, the dates when read have the following format: dd.mm.yyyy

```
//Dateformatting
function parseDate (dateStr) {

    var s1 = dateStr.split(" ");
    var s1dat = s1[0].split(".");
    return new Date(s1dat[2], s1dat[1], s1dat[0])
};



var dateArr = [];

//Occupation
d3.tsv("data.csv", function(error, data, tsv) {
    datasetIn = data;
    datasetIn.forEach(function(d) {
                                d.datum = parseDate(d.datum);
                                d.Patients =  +d.Patients.replace(",", ".");
                                d.Beds=  +d.Antal_vardplats.replace(",", ".");
                                });




    for (index = 0; index < datasetIn.length; ++index) {
        dateArr.push(datasetIn[index].datum);
    }


    var maxYear = d3.max(dateArr).getFullYear();
    var maxDate = d3.max(dateArr);
})
```

Comment: Are you aware that month values in JavaScript are zero-based? Passing in a human-readable 9 representing September to `new Date()` is supposed to create a Date object for October instead.

Comment: @altocumulus: Yeah, I've used it in other functions but forgot about it here. That's the reason then - thx!

Comment: As an aside, I was asking myself, why you are iterating over `datasetIn` twice. One iteration is within `.forEach()` and then you are doing it with a for-loop. Shouldn't you be able to add `dateArr.push(datasetIn[index].datum);` to `.forEach()` to improve readability and performance?

Comment: That was a good idea, i added the second for-loop during my error-checking phase so hadn't thought it through. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript month values are zero-based beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December. Passing in a human-readable 9 representing September to `new Date()` is supposed to create a Date object for October instead.

```
new Date("2015", "9", "7").toDateString();  // "Wed Oct 07 2015"
```

Adjusting for this should give you the correct result when parsing human-readable date values.